# How would I know the source org of the sandbox?

Tags: sandbox

I have created sandbox, I don't remember from which org it is copied from?
Is there any way to know the same? TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on the sandbox list (Setup > Quick Search > Sandboxes) on the far-right column. If this field is blank, it is Production. You can also query this from the [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) table (requires Tooling API).

Comment: "Copied From' is the column you mean?

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes, that's the one.